# How to declare the layout for 7'inch tablet Android?

Tags: android

I am developing application on both 10'inch&7'inch tablets, here is my problem for 10'inch tablet i have declared layout as(layout-xlarge-land & layout-xlarge-port),while coming to 7'inch i have declared layout as(layout-sw600dp-land&layout-sw600dp-port)?

while coming to 7'inch tablet it's not working for me,The Tablet which i am using is (iRobot).

Comment: what is not working? What happened?

Comment: for 7 inch tablet the layout design is not working for me,(layout-sw600dp-land&port)instead of these it is taking the normal layout.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In the rare case where you want to further customize your UI, For example for 7” vs. 10” tablets, you can also define smallest widths:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets
```

and just check out this for  7” vs. 10” tablets:--

[**New Tools For Managing Screen Sizes**](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011_07_01_archive.html).

Comment: You are correct Uttam but this will work only from 3.2+. Before 3.2 sw600dp is not recognized

Comment: @StErMi that's true.  And for tablets like Kindle Fire and Nook Color this code is pretty much useless.

Comment: From the link: `res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml    # For pre-3.2 tablets`

Comment: layout for 8" tablets?

Answer (score 8):

you can also specify your `layout` folder like this

1. **layout-1280x800**
2. **layout-port-1280x800**

As per new approach discussed here, [New Tools For Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)
we can specify like this

1. **layout**  *For phones*
2. **layout-sw600dp** *# For 7” tablets*
3. **layout-sw720dp** *# For 10” tablets*

Comment: 10inch tablet, like this set with the dimension of 7inch tablet

Comment: @Labeeb I just don't see how this would work for Kindle Fire and Nook Color.

Comment: It never depend on the Providers. At runtime, Android detects the current device configuration and loads the appropriate resources for your application, refer [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: @LabeebPanampullan I have a image in 'drawable-television' qualifier, but Android pick another image (same name, of course) from 'drawable-sw600dp' . I want to pick it up from 'drawable-television' folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

but if you are building for amazon devices

- kindle fire 7" uses `layout-large-mdpi`
- kindle fire 7" HD uses `layout-large-hdpi`

along with other android devices 7" which use `layout-sw600dp`

Comment: if i am developing for 7" table app and i want to use apps on all tablet mean amazon and other table also then which layout i have to mention layout-sw600dp or layout-large-mdpi??

Comment: you need to include both, amazon device would use layout-large-mdpi and layout-large-hdpi, if not present would try to use default layout and other android devices would look for layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp else try to use default layout. So, in short, all devices try to find its required layout file if not present try to use default layout (if it can be rendered without crashing).

Answer (score 5):

[**Android: Tools For Managing Screen Sizes**](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

[**Kindle Fire: Screen Layout and Resolution**](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/screen-layout.html)

- > **phones :**

  **layout**
- > **7” tablets :**

  **layout-sw600dp**
- > **10” tablets :**

  **layout-sw720dp**
- > **kindle fire 7" :**

  **layout-large-mdpi**
- > **kindle fire 7" HD :**

  **layout-large-hdpi**

Answer (score 0):

It's because your using a "cheap" (inexpensive) 7-inch tablet 480x800, so it will use sw360 up to 430dp.