# how to include a layout for 7 inch tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android.I have `layout-sw600dp/home.xml` for tablets, but it does'nt fit to it. It uses **home.xml** from normal Layout folder.

Please help me to fit the screen to 7 inches tablet.

Comment: or layout-large-mdpi acording to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763065/how-to-declare-the-layout-for-7inch-tablet-android/12649224#12649224

Comment: What is the actual logical and actual resolution of your device? Get the deatils using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pengala.displaymetrics) app

Answer (score 2):

`layout-sw600dp` is the right way to do this.
layout-xhdpi has nothing to do with tablets and layout-large is deprecated in favor of layout-sw600dp .

The problem might come from your tablet, is it a bit smaller than 7" ? if you try layout-sw500dp, does it still use the same default file ?

Comment: bro i wil check it out and come back later. thanks for ur reply

Comment: my tablet is BSNL Penta is701c

Comment: Bro no way it still use the same default file

Comment: hmmm. very weird. Then again, the BSNL Penta IS701C is not certified by Google as far as I know. So we have no guaranties that it can run the Android compatibility tests successfully. If you defined your layouts correctly, the problem is still very likely to come from the tablet. A good way to confirm it would be to test you app with the emulator on a virtual 7" tablet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit your device (BSNL Penta is701c) try layout-large-mdpi or layout-large-ldpi, because your device have very small resolution (800*480) for 7''.

But normally you should use layout-sw600dp for 7'' devices.

Comment: i used both of layout-large-mdpi and layout-large-ldpi but not useful. it takes the layout from the default one.

Comment: I think it's problem of your device, not Android. Can you test on another 7'' device or emulator?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your app manifest :

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...      
</manifest>
```