# Android 7 inch tablet 480x800

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tablet

I'm developing an android application and I have this folders in res

- layout - for handstets
- layout large - for handsets with big resolution
- layout-sw600dp - for tablets 7 inch with 640x1080 resolution
- layout-sw800dp - for 10 inch tablets

but I need a folder for tablets 7 inch with low resolution - 480x800.If I run this application on my tablet(7 inch 480x800) ,it use the layout folder but it's too small and seems ugly.How can I create a layout for this kind of tablets with low resolution,what is name of the layout folder ?

Comment: Refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7763539/1503155

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare the layout for 7'inch tablet Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763065/how-to-declare-the-layout-for-7inch-tablet-android)

Comment: The version of the tablet is 4 +

Answer (score 3):

If your device is API 13 or higher, you can use the `layout-sw<???>dp` qualifier.

For a 7 inch tablet, `layout-sw600dp` is the correct qualifier. Your specific tab with  resolution 480 x 800 should come under this category with `ldpi` density.

Conversion of px to dp: **dp = px / (dpi / 160)**. Here *px* is 480 and *dpi* is 120.
So *dp = 480/(120/160) == 600dp*

As an alternative, you can use `layout-large` qualifier. Again here you can use `layout-large-ldpi` which specifically defines your tablet.

Comment: Hm I put all files in layout-large-ldpi and the tablet don't use it , it use the layout for phones :(

Comment: I think layout-large-ldpi is for 480x800 but 5 inch.My tablet is strange 480x800 7 inch .

Comment: Hm I founde a way.I just created sw480dp folder and put all layouts in this folder ,but will this layout will conflict with phones like 5 inches

Comment: Ya, there is chance of that.. `sw480dp` may conflict with large phablet devices. According to the official docs, it should take resources from `sw600dp` folder.. Are you sure your device not taking resources from this folder??

Comment: yes because my device is 480x800,in sw600dp the min resolution is 640x1000 I tried this and it takes resource from sw600dp but my tablet is with low resolution and ..

Comment: No.no.. You are taking this wrong.. Resolution is specified in pixels and Android deals in density independent pixels(dpi). Thats why I described the conversion in the answer. and have you tried `layout-large-ldpi`??

Comment: I tested this application on tablet 7 inch with big resolution 640x1000 and it takes sw600dp folder and looks good ,but my tablet is some kind of fake :D

Comment: I removed sw480dp folder and now my tablet uses layout folder for phones and seems ugly ,but ...